# Eclipse saves all vs. only code I'm working on

Tags: eclipse

I have noticed that when I make any changes to my code in Eclipse and save my new code, all objects (triggers, classes, etc.) get stamped with my name as modifier of all those objects. Seems to me that when I save code thinking that it only saves the code i'm working on, it makes a save to everything that I have in my project in eclipse. Has anyone ever run into this? Any ideas on resolution?

Thank you!

Comment: What version are you using, and it might help to explain why it matters, because changing time stamps are rarely a problem unless they cause a problem, in which case, we need to get to the root problem.

Comment: Kepler Service Release 2